# How to store 2 million strings in a database for fast access

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, nosql

I have to store 2 million codes, being every code a string of fixed length 11. Every code has a boolean attribute called 'used', which marks the code as used or not (!). The amount of codes will be the same forever (no Create codes, no Delete codes, no Update codes) and the only update action would be to the used attribute of existing codes.

Every time a user enters a code on a web form, I have to search that code, check whether it has been used and if not, mark it as used.

There will be lots of users entering codes (up to 50 concurrently, yeah, that's lots to me!) so I wonder what would be a good approach to make my webapp not suck of slowness.

Is this feasible with postgres (the DBMS I like the most)? What feature of postgres should I explore further? Indices?

Is this kind of task best performed by nosql? Maybe redis?

I'm going to use a cloud server (rackspace). What amount of ram should I put into it? There will be other stuff happening to the database, but nothing of importance in comparison? I'm guessing 1GB.

What other things should I research?

I don't want anyone doing any research for me, just need some pointers so I can further investigate this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes a SQL database will do this.

create a table with at least two columns, used_flag and code

add indexes to the code.

Comment: I'll do that! According to the [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-constraints.html): _Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique btree index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint_. Since my codes are all different that would be all! Thanks :)

Comment: Be sure to define that table with a fillfactor of less than the default of 100% so that faster HOT updates can be used.  That makes it run faster by a factor of about 30 in my test.  Don't index on the used flag; just on the code.  Also, don't use a separate SELECT to test the current state of the code; `UPDATE ... WHERE code = x AND NOT used_flag`.  You can check the count of rows affected to see if this set the flag.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Just one thing, the [CREATE INDEX doc page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) says that _B-trees use a default fillfactor of 90_. It seems that postgres really wants to make my life simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fast enough with appropriate index code field. Database will not make 2 million iteration, with index it will be log(2) 2 million ~ 20. 20 iteration should be fast enought

Comment: That's what I'm going to try. Postgres will do the work for me, since all my codes are different and an index is automatically created for a unique field. I can't upvote yet, so thanks :)

Comment: Btrees are not binary search trees, lookup time on a cold instance should be roughly CC * D * log2(LF)) + IOC * logD(N) where CC is CompareCost, IOC is block IOCost, LF is LoadFactor (avg # keys per index block), D is tree depth (logLF(N)). IOC is usually very much greater then CC and dominates when index is not cached, but it's hard to predict how significant in the context of caching.

Comment: It does not matter, B-tree or R-tree. According to big O notation, it's log